# What does the -l argument mean in tcsh?

Tags: command-line, arguments, tcsh, set

I'm running a tcsh shell.

I have questions about the `-l` option in `set -l`.

When I look at man for the `set` command, I don't see the `-l` argument.

When using tcsh shell, what does the `-l` argument mean?

Where & how can I find this info?

Comment: Do you mean the `-l` option to `tcsh` itself? As in `tcsh -l`?

Comment: No. I mean `set -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong place. This is from the `tcsh(1)` manual page:

> ```
> set
> set name ...
> set name=word ...
> set [-r] [-f|-l] name=(wordlist) ... (+)
> set name[index]=word ...
> set -r (+)
> set -r name ... (+)
> set -r name=word ... (+)
>     The  first  form  of  the command prints the value of all shell
>     variables.  Variables which contain more  than  a  single  word
>     print  as a parenthesized word list.  The second form sets name
>     to the null string.  The third form sets  name  to  the  single
>     word.   The  fourth  form  sets  name  to  the list of words in
>     wordlist.  In all cases  the  value  is  command  and  filename
>     expanded.   If -r is specified, the value is set read-only.  If
>     -f or -l are specified, set only  unique  words  keeping  their
>     order.  -f  prefers the first occurrence of a word, and -l the
>     last.
> ```

So `set -f list=(foo bar baz foo)` will set `list` to `(foo bar baz)`,

but `set -l list=(foo bar baz foo)` will set `list` to `(bar baz foo)`,

and `set list=(foo bar baz foo)` will set it to `(foo bar baz foo`), keeping duplicates.

The only difference is how it handles duplicates in the word list. This feature is not present in the classical/real `csh`, which is now unencumbered open-source itself and (if I'm not mistaken) the default `csh` on many systems.

Answer (score 1):

In the manual for the TENEX C shell, rather than the manual for `set`.  The relevant part of the TENEX C shell manual has `-l` fourth in its synopses for the `set` command:

```
       set
       set name ...
       set name=word ...
       set [-r] [-f|-l] name=(wordlist) ... (+)
       set name[index]=word ...
       set -r (+)
       set -r name ... (+)
       set -r name=word ... (+)
```

and discusses it in the description that follows.

Look up shell builtins in the manual for the shell that they are built in to.  The manual page for `set` that you looked at might have told you to do this.  FreeBSD's manual for `set` certainly does:

```
SYNOPSIS
     See the built-in command description in the appropriate shell manual page.
```